# Changing the Top Menu from Displaying Categories to Page Links?

Tags: topmenu, ce-1.9.2.2

If this is a duplicate question, please be kind enough to point me in the right direction to a solution as I've searched already :(

Just configuring a Magento CE 1.9 template (by Templatemela) and have a question.

How can I change the Top Level Nav Menu (id=advancedmenu) to display custom website links, e.g. Contact, About Us, Terms and Conditions, Delivery etc... instead of Categories?
I have found the top.phtml file and where the Categories menu is built, but not how to add menu top level menu links.

[Link to Home Page](http://www.familyofbrandglasses.com/magento/index.php/)

I assume that there must be an easy way or something I've missed in configuring the Categories.

Thank you for any help,

Alan.

Comment: Add some code here from top.phtml file

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chirag Nandaniya. I don't quite understand what you're suggesting.